# Should my tests fail when a variable value changes

Tags: testing, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

You have automated tests / manual system tests.

Should they fail, if a variable value changes so for example:

You have an e-commerce website that has 10 products.
In production, the price change is made and the testers know what the new prices are.

But you don't update the prices in non-production environments, but the testers are saying that their tests are failing as they have updated the prices in their tests. Because they have updated the prices in their tests.

My question comes down to, how the tests are written. Should they know the price of the items, or should they just know the business rules and test these.

If a price is needed to be shown on a screen, the tests should be written in a way that identifies this and the actual value shouldn't matter just a case of 
knowing where the data comes from and where it should be shown.

Thus in my opinion tests should only need to change if the business rules / requirements change and not that the data has changed value.

Answer (score 0):

The automated tests should not in this case.

The only time when it should fail is when the flow changes meaning that the scenario needs to be updated or when there is a bug.

Is not a good practice to use this type of data hard-coded in the scenarios.The only data hard-coded should be the data that does not change,  like email addresses, passwords, addresses, credit cards.

To avoid issues like this you should save the product price in a variable before you add the product to the cart and then use that variable where you need it.

You should have a set of best practices to avoid any issues and to increase the efficiency, the maintainability and the stability of the automation suite.
Use code reviews and schedule some time for improvements if needed.

The scenarios should work for any products and in fact for any language of that environment if multiple languages exists, and yes, the tests should change only when the business requirements are changing.